# Renaming my Item with File Name as a Variable not Working using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I am using Powershell. My goal is to copy one item to a different directory (which I already know how to do), get the userID (which I already know how to do), and rename the file with a file name that exists in a variable (which I am not sure what I am doing wrong).

When I run my code, it gives me an error: **Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null.** I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I got this from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7

My code is listed below:

```
$name = [Environment]::UserName
$mainFile = "\\example\example.xlsx"
$copiedFile = "\\example\example\copiedFolder\example.xlsx"
#Once I have copied the file to the new directory, I do the following code which does not work:
$copiedFile = Rename-Item -Path $copiedFile -NewName $name.xlsx
```

Comment: Oh whoops! That was a mistake.  I will fix it.

Comment: `$copiedFile = 'D:\Temp\toto.txt'
$name = 'myName'

$copiedFile = Rename-Item -Path $copiedFile -NewName ($name + ".xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

You've way over complicated this. It's a simple copy command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\reconcile.*'
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        03-Feb-20     12:54            644 reconcile.txt
#>

$mainFile   = 'D:\temp\reconcile.txt'
$FileTarget = 'D:\temp\'
Copy-Item -Path $mainFile -Destination "$FileTarget\reconcile.xlsx" -Force
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\reconcile.*'
<#
# Results


    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        03-Feb-20     12:54            644 reconcile.txt                                                                                                 
-a----        03-Feb-20     12:54            644 reconcile.xlsx
#>
```

I am not sure why this...

```
[Environment]::UserName
```

...is in your code, and in it twice, since you are not showing how it is being used. However, you can just use the built-in variable for that.

```
$env:USERNAME
```

[About_EnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and I feel incredibly dumb for not doing it first. I thank everyone for their input and apologize for all the edits in my previous code. My problem was that I wasn't putting double quotes around $name.xlsx.

This gives me \example\example\copiedFolder\JohnDoe.xlsx Tried single quotes and gave me \example\example\copiedFolder\$name.xlsx instead. Not really sure why. See code below:

```
$copiedFile = Rename-Item -Path $copiedFile -NewName "$name.xlsx"
```